# How to bring a modal to the front of the page using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement a modal using bootstrap.  When I click on the button the screen fades and the modal appears, but it appears behind the images in  and is unreadable for the user.  How do I bring the modal forward?

```
<div class ="container-fluid">
<div class = "row-fluid">

    <div class = "span2">
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
            <h3>Modal header</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch demo modal</a>
    </div>

    <div class = "span8">       
        #a lot of images in this div
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I can't have the modal within a fixed element on the page.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is good to go; you need to include `bootstrap.css` and bootstrap `modal.js` library.

Live [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9yAv/1/).

Comment: I do have both of those included; the modal appears but it's behind all the other content on the page instead of in front of it.  Does that help?